# Error al subir imagen con Multer

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, react-native, multer

Estoy haciendo un proyecto de ecommerce y quiero guardar imagen de los productos, tengo un servidor de heroku en donde se estará guardando las imagenes.

**Servicio de upload.**

```
import express from 'express';
import multer from 'multer';
import config from '../config';

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'uploads/');
  },
  filename(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, `${Date.now()}.jpg`);
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/', upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
  res.send(`/${req.file.path}`);
});


export default router;
```

El problema es que me retorna el path pero no guarda la imagen.
Gracias por el apoyo.

Comment: Verifica la ruta en heroku ya que en el frontend tu puedes poner `mías.herokuapp.com/imgs/imagen1.jpg` y esto te devolverá la imagen

Comment: Muchas gracias, verificaré.

Comment: @christian modifiqué el detalle del problema ya que estaba viendo que no esta guardando la imagen.

Comment: no se mucho de multer pero te dejo este [enlace](https://code.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/file-upload-with-multer-in-node--cms-32088) para que veas un ejemplo y comprubes

Comment: Heroku no guarda las imágenes. El hospedaje que te da borra todos los datos cada vez que publicas una nueva versión, hay un error en el servidor, o se reinicia el mismo por cualquier causa. Necesitas un servicio externo como firebase storage o aws.

Comment: No es un problema de multer, es un problema de heroku ya que es un servicio efimero, lo que significa que no puedes agregar ni modificar archivos despues de haber hecho el deploy